# Path in Variable with r'

Tags: python, path

I want to replace this:
path = r'C:/Folder
with this:
path = r'variable

Where variable is defined elsewhere.

In not sure how to put the variable name after the r'

Comment: I think you should make your `variable` raw string at the time of declaring it. I don't think it make sense to type cast explicitly it to raw string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `path = variable`.

The point of the `r'...'` notation is for writing [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals); it changes the rules for character escaping inside of the quotes. If you're just getting the value from another variable, there's no need for an `r` since you're not writing a string literal.

Answer (score 15):

This should work:

```
path = r'%s' % variable
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add **r** to path,then this should work,but u cant add directly **r** to a path variable,because its a syntax.This can be efficiently used if u have facing **Unicode Escape Error** which occurs due to presnt of "\" in path.

Here is the code:-

```
raw_string path=path.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
```

This will work like   **r'path'**

Comment: That wasn't what the questioner was looking for.

Comment: sorry,check now @AlBlue