# MacOS - Python Selenium Geckodriver - Set Preference Download Directory is not accepting relative folder path

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Down below where I have browser.download.dir I have to use the absolute path for it to download to the directory I need it to.
But if I change it to a relative path, it downloads it to the default directory (Downloads)
I am running the script from the /Users/myname/magic/script directory

I have tried

```
./sites/pdd/notes and sites/pdd/notes
```

I have also tried

```
getdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', getdir+'/notes')
```

```
expected_download = 'sites/pdd/downloads/'
mime_types = "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml"

options = Options()
options.headless = True

# To prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/Users/myname/magic/script/sites/pdd/notes')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mime_types)
options.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", mime_types)
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'mac/geckodriver')
```

Is there a way to get around having to use the absolute path?

Comment: executable_path seems a little strange.

Comment: @Yun the r notation is for writing raw string literals.  I copied those set_preference  settings from another stackedoverflow answer, and I wondered the same thing till I looked it up.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313886/path-in-variable-with-r